# React sidebar navigation overlapping information on page when broswer is resized

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a fixed sidebar nav in react but it is overlapping my pages. All my information will be underneath the navbar when I resize my browser. Attached are the pictures. Does anyone know the issue? Thanks. enter image description here

[Before browser is resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P56VQ.png)
[After resizing browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSbxg.png)

jsx code

```
function Navbar() {const [currentTab, changeTab] = useState("Home");
 return (
    <>
    <div className='navbar'>
      <nav className='nav-menu'>
    <ul className='nav-menu-items'>
      <li className='nav-text'> Home</li>
      <li className='nav-text' >Exexution</li>
      <li className='nav-text'>review</li>
      <li className='nav-text'>profile</li>
      <li className='nav-text'>setting</li>


    </ul>

  </nav>

</div>
</>

 );
 }

 export default Navbar;
```

css code

```
.navbar{
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0 0 0 ;

  }
  .menu-bars{
     margin-left: 2rem;
      font-size: 2rem;
      background: none;

         }

    .nav-menu{
        background-color: aqua;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;

           }

        .nav-menu-item{
            width: 100%;
              }
       .nav-text{
           display: flex;
             justify-content: start;
              align-items: center;
             padding: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
           list-style: none;
          height: 60px;


           }
```

app.jsx

```
function DefaultContainer() {
   return (

     <>
       <Router>
        <Navbar />

         <Switch>
         <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
         <Route path="/execution" exact component={Execution} />
         <Route path="/review" exact component={Review} />
         <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />
         
          </Switch>
         </Router>
        </>
       );
        }
     export default App;
```

Comment: Could you put add a working example in your question? This will help others assist you quicker. Also, without knowing how your other components are laid out I would assume it's a `z-index` issue.

Comment: I don't know how to put a working example. Z-index did not solve the issue. Apparently my pages component was a whole div taking up the entire div. I can add how my components are laid out, maybe that'll make it easier?